# Getting InvalidARN, How to get ARN of ECR image?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ecr

I am trying to create a new tag or an image, for which I am using `boto3.client('ecr').tag_resource`

```
response = ecr.tag_resource(
            resourceArn=f'arn:aws:ecr:{region_name}:{account_id}:image/{repository_name}@{image_digest}',
            tags=[{'Key': 'tag-key', 'Value': image_tag}]
        )
```

Resulting output `InvalidParameterException`:

```
File ~/Documents/NuTest_Prac/nu_py3/nutest-py3/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py:530, in ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    526     raise TypeError(
    527         f"{py_operation_name}() only accepts keyword arguments."
    528     )
    529 # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File ~/Documents/NuTest_Prac/nu_py3/nutest-py3/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py:964, in BaseClient._make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    962     error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    963     error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 964     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    965 else:
    966     return parsed_response

InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the TagResource operation: Invalid parameter at 'resourceArn' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid ARN'
```

I explored much but could not find the ARN information which could help me create or get the ARN which is valid. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: What are the values of the variables that you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tag_resource` method is used for tagging AWS resources and does not have anything to do with image tags. If you want to tag an image you need to use the [put_image](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.93/reference/services/ecr/client/put_image.html) method:

```py
# Get the image's details to get its manifest
get_image_response = ecr.batch_get_image(
    registryId=account_id,
    repositoryName=repository_name,
    imageIds=[{"imageDigest": image_digest}]
)
if get_image_response["images"]:
    manifest  = get_image_response["images"][0]["imageManifest"]
    manifest_media_type = get_image_response["images"][0]["imageManifestMediaType"]
    # Tag the image
    response = ecr.put_image(
        registryId=account_id,
        repositoryName=repository_name,
        imageManifest=manifest,
        imageManifestMediaType=manifest_media_type,
        imageTag=image_tag,
        imageDigest=image_digest
    )
else:
    print("Image not found")
```